# How to initialize a const pointer to a const data of unknown size (need alloc)

Tags: c++, pointers, constructor, constants

I have the following class:

```
class A {
    A(B* b, unsigned int size_in);
private:

    unsigned int size;

    // Pointer whose address and pointed-to data shouldn't be changed
    const char* const p1;

    // Pointer which should hold a copy of p1's data (at another location in the memory).
    // Shouldn't ever be changed once copied from p1
    const char* const p1_copy;
};
```

I'm trying to understand how I should build the constructor, I want something of this functionality:

```
A::A(B* b, unsigned int size_in) :
  size(size_in), p1(b->GetPtr() + b->GetOffset())
{
  p1_copy = new char[size];
  memcpy(p1_copy, p1, size);
}
```

But I obviously can't do that to p1_copy because it is const and can only be initialized in an initialization list (also `memcpy` wouldn't work with a `const` pointer as the 1st argument).

**FYI:** after the constructor is executed, I will never change `p1` or `p1_copy`.

What's the proper way to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option could be to create a function which makes a copy of the string:

```
char* copyString(const char* s, size_t size) {
    char* copy = new char[size];
    memcpy(copy, s, size);
    return copy;
}

A::A(B* b, unsigned int size_in) :
  size(size_in), p1(b->GetPtr() + b->GetOffset()),
  p1_copy(copyString(p1, size_in))
{
}
```

Another option, which I would prefer, is just to use `std::string` instead of raw pointer:

```
class A {
    //...
    const std::string p1_copy;
};

A::A(B* b, unsigned int size_in) :
  size(size_in), p1(b->GetPtr() + b->GetOffset()),
  p1_copy(p1, p1 + size_in)
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are probably a few different solutions for this, but this is the typical case that `const_cast` was designed for - where you temporarily want to override the `const`ness of something.

So, you want something like (it can be done without a temporary variable, but you need more const_cast operations, and it's much less clear.

```
  char* tmp = new char[size];
  memcpy(tmp, p1, size);
  const_cast<const char*>(p1_copy) = tmp;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the proper/best way, but couldn't you do something like

```
const char* copy(const char* a, int size) {
    const char* ret = new char[size];
    memcpy(ret, a, size);
    return ret;
}
```

and then

```
A::A(B* b, unsigned int size_in) :
  size(size_in), p1(b->GetPtr() + b->GetOffset()), p1_copy(copy(p1, size)) {}
```